# Word interop Range: expanding by a line unit considered a bad parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-word, vsto, word-2013

This is attempted inside an Application-level add-in.
The documentation for [expanding a Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.expand(v=office.14).aspx) indicates that supplying a `WdUnits` parameter as a reference object should succeed. And it does, for most of the `WdUnits` collection. But, bafflingly, not for `WdUnits.wdLine`. The following code seems to always fail:

```
object lineUnit = WdUnits.wdLine;
var rng = document.Range(document.Content.Start, document.Content.Start);
// throws COMException with ErrorCode -2146824168: Bad Parameter
tempRange.Expand(ref lineUnit);
```

but the same operation on a `Selection` succeeds:

```
object lineUnit = WdUnits.wdLine;
document.Range(document.Content.Start, document.Content.Start).Select();
// Word groks this happily
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Expand(ref lineUnit);
```

Why on earth is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

You know, I consider that a bug in the interop. The way I got around it was to use wdSentence and write other code for tables (to identify rows).  I had to do this for my DeleteWhere wrapper method.

```
        public bool DeleteWhere(string value, StringContentType type = StringContentType.Item, bool caseSensitive = true)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            bool ret = false;
            if (type == StringContentType.Line)
            {
                ret = DeleteRowWhere(value, caseSensitive);
            }
            object mytype = type.ToWdUnits();
            if (type == StringContentType.Line)
            {
                mytype = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdSentence;
            }
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = doc.Content;
            object matchword = true;
            while (range.Find.Execute(value, caseSensitive, matchword))
            {
                range.Expand(ref mytype);
                range.Delete();
                ret = true;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        private bool DeleteRowWhere(string value, bool caseSensitive = true)
        {
            bool ret = false;
            string search = caseSensitive ? value : value?.ToUpperInvariant();
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table table in doc.Tables)
            {
                for (int x = 1; x <= table.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 1; y <= table.Columns.Count; y++)
                    {
                        string val = caseSensitive ? table.Cell(x, y).Range.Text : table.Cell(x, y).Range.Text?.ToUpperInvariant();
                        if (val != null && val.Contains(search))
                        {
                            table.Rows[x].Delete();
                            ret = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
```